# Django - counting 'depth' of 'select_related' to get know how many nodes has object to top object

Tags: django, django-models

For example if I have model class like this:

```
class Category(models.Model)
    parent = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
```

And i have instance of Category that have parent which parent has albo has parent, is there possibility to get value of which children is my instance from the top Category? And also is there possibility to count somehow depth of the deepest related object of some of my Category instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need trees of model instances, take a look at [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) or [django-treebeard](https://bitbucket.org/tabo/django-treebeard/). They both provide a lot of convenience.

Comment: I will look at them and i think that i use one of them. Thanks.